# Check if array contains two specific values

Tags: javascript

I have an array and I need to check if that array contains 2 and 3.

For example `a = [1, 3]`.

I can do it with

```
a.includes(2) && a.includes(3)
```

I tried the following but I get inconsistent result, I don't understand why:

```
a.includes(1 && 3)
// true
a.includes(1 && 2)
// false
a.includes(2 && 3)
// true
```

Comment: Includes() cannot accept two arguments like that. You can find out more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a.includes(1 && 3)` doesnot pass two arguments two the function. `1 && 3` is an expression which evaluates to the first falsy value value. If there is no falsy value the last value is returned. So `1 && 3` evaluates to `3`

```js
console.log(1 && 3) //3
```

You can use `every()`

```
[1,2].every(x => a.includes(x))
```